# C# Library assembly issue

Tags: c#, .net, dll

Good Morning Everybody,

I have a problem when I did some changes into the DLL than I am using into a HMI development. First, I made some changes into the DLL, then I compile it and replace the older DLL into my HMI project folder with the new compiled DLL. After this, I had a problem with my HMI. The graphic window interface does not show the Form and the following error appears:

*The type 'MyType' could not be found. Ensure that the assembly containing the type is referenced. If the assembly is part of the current development project, ensure that the project has been built.*

in spanish:
*"No se encuentra el tipo 'mitipo'. Asegúrese de que se hace referencia al ensamblado que contiene este tipo. Si el tipo forma parte de su proyecto de desarrollo, asegúrese de que el proyecto se haya compilado correctamente con el valor de la plataforma actual o Cualquier CPU"*

I will appreciate any help anyone can give me.

best regars,

Carlos P.

Comment: Is 'MyType' part of the DLL that you have modified and replaced in your project?

Comment: You might have to re-reference the dll in the project that is using it, either that or you have changed the type MyType to be private or renamed it in the dll and it is being referenced in the code

Comment: Is your DLL strong named?

Comment: try to rebuild you HMI project after cleaning the solution.

Comment: might even need to delete *both* **obj** and **bin** folder in your HMI project. And then build the Solution

Comment: I agree with the above. I migrated a project from VS2012 to VS2015, and then I changed the framework from 3.5 to 4.6 on all of the projects. I was getting all sorts of errors like that when I tried to build. I ended up having to purge `obj` and `bin` for all of the projects (I have a BAT file to do it), and then I manually built them in the order it's supposed to do automatically. The errors went away after that.

Comment: Which version of .NET is the library and the application built for?

Comment: Im working on Visual Studio Ultimate 2013, Version 12.0.30723.00 Update 3 and Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.01038

Comment: Hello everybody...to solve the issue I had to compile the new DLL again, but I had to do it from the trunk folder where are located all HMI files and others DLLs, coz if I compiled it from the branch folder,  for some reason that I dont understand, the new DLL compiled had problems. Thanks so much for your help and ideas.

Answer (score 0):

1. You've changed [namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/z2kcy19k.aspx). Restore old value
2. You've changed [assembly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173099.aspx) name. Restore old value
3. You use a few projects and not all projects was build. Make shure all projects was build with no errors